# Differentiation problems showing that a function is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have two problems I'm stuck trying to do, the first one my solution is underneath and I think it's correct but I'm not sure so if someone could clarify that would be great,

**Question**
Given the function $$f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$$ Show that the function $$f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$$ $$x \mapsto (x+1)^3$$ is diferentiable.

**My attempt:**
        If the limit $$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$ exists then it's denoted as $f'(c)$ so we have that $$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{(x+1)^3-(c+1)^3}{x-c}$$ $$=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{(x^3+3x^2+3x+1)-(c^3+3c^2+3c+1)}{x-c}$$ $$=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{-(c-x)(c^2+cx+3c+x^2+3x+3)}{x-c}$$ $$\lim_{x\to c}({c^2+cx+3c+x^2+3x+3})$$ $$=3c^2+6c+3$$ $$=3(c+1)^2$$ therefore the limit exists and is denoted $$f'(c)=3(c+1)^2$$ i,e $$f'(x)=3(x+1)^2$$ Part (b)

Give an example of a  function $$g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$$ that is differentiable but the derivative $g'$ is not differentiable i was thinking $g(x)=x^{-2}$ but  i don't think that's correct

Comment: you may want to break this into separate questions

Comment: The beginning part of question 1 needs restating. And why call it question 1 if there are no other questions?

Answer (score 1):

For the second problem, note that $|\sin(x)|=\sin(x)$ if $\sin(x)\geq 0$ and $-\sin(x)$ if $\sin(x) < 0$, which are both differentiable.

Thus, you need to check what happens at the troublesome points where the sign of $\sin(x)$ changes. This occurs at multiples of $\pi$. By symmetry, we can examine one of these points, say $0$ wlog. The difference quotient:
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{|\sin(x)|}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1
$$
but 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{|\sin(x)|}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{-\sin(x)}{x}=-1
$$